# sortable and draggable not working together. Sortable appears to ovverride the x axis constrainment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get sortable working together with  draggable and have som eboxes possible to sort but restrict the sorting elements to be dragged outside its wrapper element.

Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jsMR4/

What happens is that sortable plugin seems to override the axis: 'x' option of draggable and then any element can be dragged in any place in the document instead of the wrapping container.

I hope you guy can suggest somthing to get thse working together and achieve the desired behaviour.

Thanks a lot!

Regards,
byte_slave